# IF comparando com GET não funciona

Tags: php

Olá. Estou tentando fazer uma comparação no PHP e o IF não funciona por nada. Já tentei de várias maneiras e não funcionou.

O código é:

```
        if(($_GET['categoria']) == 0) {
    $mysql = new conexao();
    echo 'Erro';
    }else{
    $mysql = new conexao();
    $result = $mysql->sql_query("select * from TB_GALERIA where CATEGORIA=".$_GET['categoria']." ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div class="item">';
            echo '<a class="item-hover" href="../../../uploads/midia/15989/maior_maior_DSC_0108.jpg">';
            echo '<img src="images/'.$row["IMAGEM"].'" alt="imagem galeria" class="img-responsive lazyOwl" data-src="/images/';
            echo $row["IMAGEM"];
            echo '">';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</div>';

        }
    }
```

O que está de errado com o if? Obrigado!

Comment: Tem algum erro?

Comment: Quais foram os testes realizados? Verificou qual é o valor do `$_GET` que está chegando? Coloca isso na pergunta também.

Comment: Não retorna mensagem de erro, é apenas como se o $_GET não retornasse nada. Mas por exemplo, se eu abro uma galeria existente (com o id dela), ela abre normalmente. É como se a categoria buscada não fosse encontrada, ao invés de fazer a ação ordenada no IF. O $_GET está puxando os valores normalmente, já que quando acesso as categorias existentes elas abrem normalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, antes de acessar um valor dentro do $_GET é melhor verificar se o valor existe utilizando [isset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php).

Segundo, é melhor [comparar](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) com três sinais de igualdade "===", pois assim você compara o valor e o tipo, pois "false == 0" é verdadeiro, mas "false === 0" é falso:

```
if( isset($_GET['categoria']) )
{
    if( $_GET['categoria'] === 0 )
    {
        // faz tudo que tem que fazer...
    }
}
```

Para ver o que está dentro do $_GET, sugiro fazer o seguinte:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_GET);
echo "</pre>";

die(); // pra não continuar o script, e você focar no $_GET
```

Se a comparação não está resultando em algo esperado, então o valor do $_GET não foi preenchido como deveria.

Answer (score 1):

Se você chamar somente o script, sem passar nenhum valor no parametros ele sempre será igual a 0, neste caso você deveria primeiro verificar se ele foi passado usando

```
    if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'categoria' ] ) {
            echo 'Faltou a categoria';
            exit;
    }

    if ( $_GET[ 'categoria' ] == 0 ) {
            // ...
    } else {
            // ...
    }
```

Acho que é isto!

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser manter da mesma forma que está fazendo o erro está nos parentes que você colocou no if. Segue abaixo a correção.

```
if($_GET['categoria'] == 0) {
$mysql = new conexao();
echo 'Erro';
}else{
$mysql = new conexao();
$result = $mysql->sql_query("select * from TB_GALERIA where CATEGORIA=".$_GET['categoria']." ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div class="item">';
        echo '<a class="item-hover" href="../../../uploads/midia/15989/maior_maior_DSC_0108.jpg">';
        echo '<img src="images/'.$row["IMAGEM"].'" alt="imagem galeria" class="img-responsive lazyOwl" data-src="/images/';
        echo $row["IMAGEM"];
        echo '">';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';

    }
}
```